# How to create a path that starts exactly from the center of an object?

Tags: inkscape, vector

I am trying to create animation paths to animate the elements of an svg image along paths using some javascript library.

The various objects in the image will have to follow paths, but the animation library aligns the object's center point to the path.

I have made the paths, but I can't find a way to align their to the objects center. The main problem is that the objects must be exactly adjacent because they are slices of a bigger illustration.

So my question is how can I turn the center point of one object into an actual point.

Comment: You can not. There is also no such thing as centre, there are several things that can be considered centre. It is probably usinng either coordinate 0,0 or bounding box center. Neither of which are good candidates for center of object.

Comment: The js library is green sock fwiw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know how useful this will be for your particular use case.

However, it is possible to add a single point to a shape in Inkscape at an object's midpoint/rotation centre. You could then potentially group both shape and that point, and use that point as the animation centre.

But, I'm not sure how practical this would be to use with your particular javascript library. I suppose it would depend if it can animate a group, but with respect to just one path within that group? If so, it might be a usable hack.

Here's an example, and how I would achieve it in Inkscape.

1. Draw a regular polygon or any shape, and switch on Snapping, and Snap Centres of objects. The center of a polygon will be the object centre in Inkscape, if you have a normal path, you can click a shape twice to enable the rotation handles and drag the rotation centre to anywhere you desire.
2. Draw a short straight line from that center

[image]

3. Open up the XML editor, delete the last two numbers of the path, then press enter to confirm. Perhaps rename the path ID to "center" so you easily reference it.

[image]

4. Now you have a point - an invisible path with only one node, called "center"
5. Open up the Objects panel, select both paths and group.

[image]

Here's the SVG if you want to try playing with it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="210mm" height="297mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 210 297" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<g transform="translate(59.3 -5.86)" fill="none" stroke="#000" stroke-width=".5">
<path d="m-22.6 45.8c-1.89.97-9.84-8.64-11.6-9.79-1.79-1.16-13.8-4.45-13.7-6.58s12.4-4.2 14.3-5.17c1.89-.97 10.8-9.73 12.5-8.58 1.79 1.16-2.56 12.8-2.67 15-.107 2.13 3.05 14.2 1.16 15.2z"/>
<path id="center" d="m90.4 42.4"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: This pretty much solves my problem which was about aligning the start/end of the animation paths to the center of objects. Thank you!